# assigning to local variables in scala template in play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to define the local variables and assign to them as below :

```
@defining((Json.parse(value), ("GGGGGG"))) {case (json:JsValue, lb)=>
    @{lb=json\\"myTestField"}
}
```

but getting the error `reassignment to val`. So I tried to declare `lb` as `var` like

```
@defining((Json.parse(value), ("GGGGGG"))) {case (json:JsValue, lb:var)=>
    @{lb=json\\"myTestField"}
}
```

but getting the error `identifier expected but 'var' found`

How can I assign to variable `lb`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do something like that?

Comment: I am passing json data to my view and want to display each fields value on the browser in user readable text and not in JSON format itself. Can it be done in some other way?

Comment: You should parse it in your controller, not in your view. Your view should be as dumb as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can assign to a val and use it further down in your view.  What you are doing should really be done in the controller.

```
@someValue = @{
             //your logic to assign to someValue
             }
             //pass value to another view
             @anotherView(someValue)
```

Edit as per comment below:

```
 @Json.parse(value) match {

                        case Some(value) if value == "GGGGGG" => {
                             <div>@value</div>
                        }
                        case _ => {
                        <div>some default value</div>
                        }

                        }
```

Comment: tried doing : `@lb=@{json\\"myTestField"}` but getting `GGGGGG=4` where 4 is value of `myTestField`. I am passing the json data to my view and letting it decide how to display this data.

Comment: Please check out my edit above.  Perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign anything else to `lb` since `lb` is a val. Pattern matching is working in this way and it is done on purpose.

Comment: Is also does not seem possible to initialize the `lb` with some value from `json` at the time of declaration.